# Trig integral and u substitution

Tags: integration

I think I made a mistake but not entirely sure, I also calculated the integral using $sin(a)*cos(b) = 1/2[sin(a-b) + sin(a+b)$ and got a different answer, which is $\frac{(-1)^{(n+1)} - 1}{\pi(n^2 -1)}$
Can someone suggest the mistake in the below calculation and also the correct answer?

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} Sin(t)Cos(nt) dt  $$

using $ u = t -\frac{\pi}{2} $ substitution gives:
 $$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} Sin(u+\pi/2)Cos(n(u+\pi/2)) du   $$
 $$ = 0 $$ as the integrand is odd.

Comment: $\sin(u+\frac{\pi}{2})$ is not odd with respect to $u$! In fact, $sin(u+\frac{\pi}{2})= \cos(u)$ which is an even function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @felasfa pointed out, $\sin(u+\pi/2) = \cos(u)$. On the other hand,
$$\cos\left(nu+n\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \begin{cases}
\cos(nu) &\text{ if $n\equiv 0 \,{\rm mod}\, 4$} \\
\sin(nu) &\text{ if $n\equiv 1 \,{\rm mod}\, 4$} \\
-\cos(nu) &\text{ if $n\equiv 2\,{\rm mod}\, 4$} \\
-\sin(nu) &\text{ if $n\equiv 3 \,{\rm mod}\, 4$}.
\end{cases}$$
You should check the above formula for yourself, but it's really just applying periodicity and the cofunction relations. In the case where $n$ is odd (i.e., either $1$ or $3$ modulo $4$), the integral is zero since the integrand will be the product of an odd and even function and hence is odd. The integral is nonvanishing when $n$ is even. This is in agreeance with your first formula, where the numerator vanishes for odd $n$.

Your first answer is almost correct. I think you lost a factor of $1/2$ somewhere though, since it should be:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^\pi\sin(t)\cos(nt)\,dt = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}-1}{2\pi(n^2-1)}.$$